# How can i call a Method in App.xaml.cs from Mainpage.xaml.cs in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a quick question here. Can any one please help me to sort out this problem.

I'm new to windows Phone. I'm developing an Application where i can change my Font styles for the entire application . I have three different Resource file to set three different types of font styles. The resource file are set to application in App.xaml.cs file. Now i need to support to change the styles in Application run time from Application Changestyles page. So i need to call the method in app.xaml.cs from changestyles.xaml.cs page.

```
private void LoadResourceDictionary()
{

    var dictionaries = new ResourceDictionary();

    string source = String.Format("/Testapp;component/Large.xaml");
    var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative) };
    dictionaries.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeStyles);

    App.Current.Resources = dictionaries;

    ResourceDictionary appResources = App.Current.Resources;
}
```

I need to call this method to set the another resource to my application in run time.

Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make this method public static and you can call it from everywhere: App.LoadResourceDictionary();

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic how to based on the code I needed for an app I am writing. I know the circumstances are slightly different, but it may help someone else who is after a similar solution:

In MainPage.xaml you create a method as follows:

```
public static void InMainPage()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi I am a method in MainPage.xaml.cs");
}
```

Now in App.xaml.cs you can call it in any method as such:

```
MainPage.InMainPage();
```

AND IT WORKS FOR YOU CIRCUMSTANCE IN THE REVERSE DIRECTION

In App.xaml.cs you create a method as follows:

```
public static void InAppXaml()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hi I am a method in App.xaml.cs");
}
```

Now in Mainpage.xaml.cs you can call it in any method as such:

```
App.InAppXaml();
```

Tested and works well.  Hope it helps!